# Write Response OutputStream

Tags: java, api

I'm trying attachment file to response (API).
I found code:

```
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileZipName + "\"");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
     out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
```

Look like it work, but I dont know about byte[] buffer = new byte[4096], what is it ? and 4096 what it mean ?

Can you help me in this case ?

Thanks all!

Comment: 4096 is size of byte array. I think you need to read about array.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];` means you have initialized a byte type of array having size `4096` bytes only. That means your only able to write only `4096` bytes into `buffer` array

Answer (score 1):

Read the data to the cache and send it through the output stream to the object server,4096 is equal to 4 * 1024 bytes,is the size of data that is read to the cache each time